# I want to read all the list items by swiping touch event

Tags: java, android, for-loop, arraylist, text-to-speech

I have a arraylist as `messagee` and i am using listview so that when I swipe up it will speak one by one item using tts engine. but problems is that it only speaks 0 th index item. but I want like when user swipe first it reads 0 th index item then again swipe ups it reads 1st index item so on..
How to achieve this?
Here is my code:-

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchEvent) {
        switch (touchEvent.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                x1 = touchEvent.getX();
                y1 = touchEvent.getY();

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                x2 = touchEvent.getX();
                y2= touchEvent.getY();



                if(y1>y2){
                    int i;
                    for( i =0;i<messagee.size();i++){
                        textTospeech.speak(messagee.get(i),TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
                        i=i+1;
                    }



                }


                break;


        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int swipeCount =0;                                            
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchEvent) {
    switch (touchEvent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x1 = touchEvent.getX();
            y1 = touchEvent.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            x2 = touchEvent.getX();
            y2 = touchEvent.getY();
            if (y1 > y2) {
                int i;
                if (swipeCount <= messagee.size()) {
                    textTospeech.speak(messagee.get(swipeCount), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    swipeCount++;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it remain speaking `0th` index item.

Comment: it only speaks 0th item, or speaks 0th item n times.? Also , in your `for loop` you are increasing `i` values twice. `i=i+1;` is not needed

Comment: ohk i have changed this but problem is when I swipe it speaks all the items because i have implemented this in for loop but i want when user swipe 2nd time it reads 2nd index position item.

Comment: I have already given in the question

Comment: ok sorry I might have misunderstood the question. 
To achieve this you need to remove for loop and maintain swipe count in a field variable. Increment it on each action up event.

Comment: Can you please edit you code because I'm not getting that swipe count

Comment: Great bro.... its working. Now I'm accepting your answer.